# EF Core and loading related data optimally

Tags: entity-framework-core

Let's say I have a structure like this

```
class User
{
    public List<UserAlbum> Albums;
    ...
}

class Album
{
    ...
}

class UserAlbum
{
    int UserId;
    int AlbumId;

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    User user;

    [ForeignKey("AlbumId")]
    Album album;
}
```

Then I load my data like this

```
User user = await Users
    .Include(u => u.UserAlbums).ThenInclude(ua => ua.album)
    // here we have a 9 more similar structures included to User
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == user.Id);
```

This works fine. The problem is that each `Include()` generates a query from `Users` table (as in `SELECT ... FROM UserAlbums INNER JOIN Users ...`). Also because `Albums` are queried in the same query, we cannot cache the response (each user has own cache entry for Albums).

So let's say 10 users log in and we retrieve all data for the users, this generates a total of:

- 110 queries to `User` table (11 per user)
- 10 queries to `Albums` table
- ... and 10 queries for each similar structure we have

So with 10 tables of related data we have a whopping 210 queries for 10 users. This could be done in 10 (users) + 100 (related data) = 120 queries. So almost double the amount of queries that is actually needed!

Of course this can be done by combining the related data manually with separate cacheable queries to tables such as Albums. But this results in a messy code and I'm wondering how are you tackling this issue?

Comment: What EF Core version is this? With latest stable at this time 2.2, the LINQ query in question (and similar) should execute total 2 SQL queries - one for user data and one for related `UserAlbums` and `Album`, in other words, same as explicit loading approach in your self answer.

Answer (score 0):

For these queries then I always use the middle table be the lambda. In this case

```
(from au in _db.UserAlbums where row.User.Id = "whatever"
select au).Include(ua => ua.Album).Include(ua => ua.User)
```

I use sql syntax, but it should be ok for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that when you use `Explicit loading` like this you won't get additional queries for the User table!

```
await database.Entry(this).Collection(u => u.albums).Query().Include(a => a.album).LoadAsync();
```

Comment: Seeing "`(this)`", it seems that you run this code in the `User` class. Then how does a user obtain a reference to the context? It's a very bad anti pattern to reverse the context-entity relationship.

Comment: Database context is just passed to the User's method where we load related entities. Yes I understand this is not very intuitive but this being my first project with EF Core I've made some mistakes. Codebase is large and in production so it's kind of hard to make large changes because of time and money.